# Spring Social Facebook Login

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, spring-social

I have follow basic Spring Social Facebook and it worked. But it required me to login on browser.

Do you have any idea how to login with an email and password that input inside the Spring program ?

Diagram:

Other Program (Send email and password) -> Java Spring application (Received and Auth) -> Facebook

Answer (score 1):

Use this opensource library, provided the library to integrate with spring

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithSpring

Answer (score 0):

This how spring Social login works.
On click of social login, your application will redirect to social provider auth server page,where user provide his own credentials and it authenticate with soical provider and then redirects to application and a connection is prepared for this social user and a local user is mapped to this connection for further access.

There is no point of consuming email and password inside of spring application.You dont have control over social user credentials.

All if you want to consume user details,you should go with spring form login.

Here is the [application](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample) & [blog](http://sunilkumarpblog.blogspot.in/2016/04/social-login-with-spring-security.html) that supports both form-login and social login(linkedin/twitter/facebook).Hope it will help you.